# What's the meaning of "close call" in Collins Dictionary?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, word-meaning, dictionaries

Source:

> There have been several *close calls*, but no one has been able to consummate a deal.

(https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/consummate)

As far as I know, "close call" means "a narrow escape from danger or disaster". What do "close calls" have anything to do with "consummate/fulfil a deal"?

Comment: It's impossible to be sure without knowing the context; a close escape is not necessarily from a very bad thing, and a deal is not necessarily good for everyone. It might be used either neutrally or jocularly; someone might say jokingly "I've never been married, but there have been one or two close calls".

Comment: There is no context, but only one sentence in the dictionary. @StuartF

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although 'close call' is *usually* used to refer to bad situations that were narrowly escaped, it can be used to refer to anything that either happened or did not happen by a narrow margin.

The origin of the phrase, like so many English sayings, is from *sport*. In several sports, a 'call' is a decision made by a referee or umpire, and a 'close call' would be one where the margin between clear decisions is so slight that it could potentially have gone either way. As the *literal* use of the phrase could result in either a positive or a negative outcome, it isn't surprising that in figurative use it can be used either way.